# Tradingview pine script calculating next RSI

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I'm trying to write code to calculate next bar RSI. Assume that last 3 closes are 3,4 and 5 and there is a RSI value in 3 bar. How can I find the next RSI value if next close is 8?

I try to create a series float 4, 5, 8 to send ta.rsi() function. How can create a series float in each bar manually like this.

`seriesFloatVariable = 4 seriesFloatVariable := 5 seriesFloatVariable := 8 ta.rsi(seriesFloatVariable,3)`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to calculate the next bar price value so that RSI value will be 70. Here, 70 is an example, it can be any value.